# SwiftでPythonのtime.time()と同じような出力結果を得る時間取得方法はありますか？

Tags: python, swift

Pythonでは、以下のようなコードを書くと

```
import time
print(time.time())
```

以下のような出力結果が得られます。

```
1614759056.6246538
```

この出力結果は全て数字のみで構成されており、前回計測時の時間と足し算や引き算などに使用しやすいです。

Swiftの場合は、以下のように日時を取得できます。

```
import UIKit
let dt : Date = Date()
print(dt)
```

しかし、この取得方法だと以下のような出力結果になります。

```
2021-03-03 17:16:05 +0000
```

求める出力結果と大きく異なっており、過去に書いたPythonコードをSwiftに変換するのに手間取っています。
何か良い方法はありますでしょうか？

Comment: この記事あたりでしょうか。[Date to milliseconds and back to date in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40134323/9014308), [TimeInterval](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timeinterval), [TimeInterval関数について](https://teratail.com/questions/232685), [Swiftで経過時間を表示する](https://mt312.com/785)

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pythonのことはあまり詳しくないですが、おそらく欲しいのはエポック秒のようですね。

```
Date().timeIntervalSince1970
```

参考資料：
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096602/get-unix-epoch-time-in-swift

Comment: ありがとうございます、これが求めていたものでした